# Overriding and Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

i am having problems with my codes. this is our assignment:

> "Write a superclass named clsWorker and subclasses clsHourlyWorker and clsSalariedWorker. Every worker has a name and a salary rate. Write a method computePay(int hours) that computes the weekly pay for every worker. An hourly worker gets paid the hourly wage for the actual number of hours worked if hours is at most 40. If the hourly worker worked for more than 40 hours, the excess is paid at time and a half. The salaried worker gets paid the hourly wage for 40 hours, no matter what the actual number of hours is. Write a test program for the inheritance. Input the name of the worker, the number of hours worked and the type of worker, H for hourly and S for salaried, the salary rate of the worker. Display the salary of every worker entered."

we need to do overriding and inheritance. i always encounter the NoSuchMethodError

My superclass:

```
     public class clsWorker
{   
    int hours=0,excess=0;
    double salary,newSalary=0.0;
    String sType;


    public clsWorker()
    {

    }

    public clsWorker(double sal,String type)
    {
        //this.hours=hours;
        salary=sal;
        sType=type;
    }

    public double computePay(int hours)
    {   
        sType=sType.toUpperCase();
        if(sType.equals("H"))       
        newSalary=(salary*hours)*7;
        else if(sType.equals("S"))
        {   if(hours>=40)
            newSalary=salary*40;
            else if(hours>40)
            {
            excess=hours-40;
            newSalary=(newSalary+((newSalary*excess)*1.5))*7;
            }
        }
        return newSalary;       
    }


}
```

My subclasses

```
public class clsHourlyWorker extends clsWorker
    {   
        double dSalary=0.0;
        int iHours=0;

        public clsHourlyWorker()
        {
            //super();
        }

        public clsHourlyWorker(int iHours, double salaryph,String sRate)
        {

            super(iHours,salaryph,sRate);   
            //clsWorker w=new clsWorker();
            dSalary=newSalary;  

        }




        public double getSalary()
        {
            return dSalary;
        }
    }

public class clsSalariedWorker extends clsWorker
{
    double dSalary=0.0;
    int iHours=0;   

    public clsSalariedWorker()
    {
        //super();
    }

    public clsSalariedWorker(int iHours,double salaryph,String sRate)
    {

        super(iHours,salaryph,sRate);
        //super(salaryph,sRate);
        //this.iHours=iHours;   
        //clsWorker w=new clsWorker();
        dSalary=newSalary;
    }

    /*public void setSalary(int iHourjs)
    {

    }*/ 

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return dSalary;
    }
}
```

my test class

```
import java.util.*;

public class testSalary
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Input Salary per hour: ");
        double salaryph=console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input number of hours: ");
        int iHours=console.nextInt();
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input Worker Name: ");
        String sName=console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input Type of Worker: ");
        String sRate=console.next();


        clsHourlyWorker hw=new clsHourlyWorker(iHours,salaryph,sRate);
        clsSalariedWorker sw=new clsSalariedWorker(iHours,salaryph,sRate);

        //System.out.println("Worker Name: "+sName+"\nSalary: "+hw.getSalary());
        if(sRate.equals("H"))
        System.out.println("Worker Name: "+sName+"\nSalary: "+hw.getSalary());
        else if (sRate.equals("S"))
        System.out.println("Worker Name: "+sName+"\nSalary: "+sw.getSalary());


    }

}
```

can someone tell me how to fix my problem? thanks.

Comment: What line of code causes your error?

Comment: Is that really the text of your actual assignment? If yes, then it's unfortunate that it is not following the Java naming convention. Class name should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I think your `clsWorker` should really have been made abstract.

Comment: What's `newSalary`?  This is referenced a couple times but never defined.

Comment: sorry. i just posted the wrong superclass. i already pasted the real one.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense:

```
    public clsHourlyWorker(int iHours, double salaryph,String sRate)
    {

        super(iHours,salaryph,sRate);   
        //clsWorker w=new clsWorker();
        dSalary=newSalary;  

    }
```

Since the super class's constructor doesn't take int, double, and String but rather, it takes String, double, int representing name, dRate, and hours. Also is sRate really supposed to be a *String*? I strongly doubt it.

I suggest that your child class constructor accept in the parameter all the information needed for the super constructor (a Strinng for name, double for dRate and int for hours) plus additional parameters the additional information for the new child class fields. You may wish to re-think those fields though as some seem to be duplicates of the super's fields and thus unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things could be improved:

## Use inheritance

Simply put, the code you posted does not leverage the power of inheritance at all. You created two subclasses, but all they do is delegate the payment computation back to the superclass. Make `clsWorker` abstract, make `computePay` abstract and implement two different versions of the method in the subclasses:

```
public abstract class Worker {
    // ...
    public abstract double computePay(int hours);
}

public class HourlyWorker extends Worker {
    // ...
    @Override
    public double computePay(int hours) {
        // code from the 'sType.equals("H")' block
    }
}

public class SalariedWorker extends Worker {
    // ...
    @Override
    public double computePay(int hours) {
        // code from the 'sType.equals("S")' block
    }
}
```

Now you will also realize that the field `sType` is not serving any useful purpose. In fact, this approach would be required only if polymorphism was not supported by Java. You already know (when writing the code) whether you're dealing with an HourlyWorker or a SalariedWorker because you put the code either in `HourlyWorker`'s `computePay` or in `SalariedWorker`'s `computePay`.

`sType` does not provide any new information that we would not already know from looking at the inheritance hierarchy. This way, you're giving the exact same information twice (once by inheritance, once by `sType`), which is something we're generally trying to avoid in software development.

## Improve "test" class

(I put "test" in quotes because most developers would think that by "test" class, you mean some sort of automated, unit-testing "test" - e.g. a JUnit test case.)

First thing that seems odd is: Why instantiate both a HourlyWorker and a SalariedWorker (i.e. `new clsHourlyWorker`, `new clsSalariedWorker`), if the user can choose to either create a HourlyWorker *or* a SalariedWorker before (but not both, this is 'exclusive or')?

What you really want is something along the lines of:

```
    Worker w;
    if(sRate.equals("H"))
        w = new HourlyWorker(iHours,salaryph);
    else if (sRate.equals("S"))
        w = new SalariedWorker(iHours,salaryph);
    else
        throw new Exception("Don't recognize worker type: " + sRate);

    System.out.println("Worker Name: "+sName+"\nSalary: "+w.getSalary());
```

As you can see, it is valid to use the abstract superclass `Worker` as the type for your worker instance variable, `w`, if you don't know at this point (during runtime) whether the user will choose `H` or `S`. You only need to access `getSalary`, which is declared in `Worker`, so everyhing is fine. (If you ever later needed to access a method which is implemented only by a subclass, you could still type-cast it.)

You will also realize that you need only one `println`. Again, we'd like to minimize duplication in favor of abstraction. Both lines do basically the same, they print name and computed salary of a worker, so we try to reduce two lines to one, more abstract line of code.

Second, you might also, instead of printing `sName` directly, want to have a getter (`getName`) in `Worker`. When you get to work on larger projects, you'll see that input and output can happen at a very different time and place (e.g. `Worker` might be stored in a database and the original variable `sName` will be long gone when a different user retrieves the `Worker` from the database). So be prepared to get all required data from your real objects, not the test input.

Third - but I might be mistaken here - "Display the salary of *every* worker entered" sounds to me like you're supposed to implement a `while` loop where the user can enter multiple workers. But then, there are more important things you can learn from this assignment.

## Follow naming conventions

In Java, it is very common practice to have uppercase class names and lowercase method names. Normally you'd have Worker, HourlyWorker and SalariedWorker (see code sample above). This way, every Java developer in the world can already tell we're talking about classes.

However, for your assignment, I'd suggest you follow whatever arbitrary "conventions" there are - just keep in mind that this is not the standard Java way. Read up on naming conventions (general and particular) before you do something like this in real-world projects.